# Sending Email using AWS SES error "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I want to send an email via aws ses and have an output of this: `print(result_by_time['TimePeriod']['Start'], '\t', '\t'.join(group['Keys']), '\t', amount, '\t', unit, '\t', result_by_time['Estimated'])`

But I got an error `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse
import boto3
import datetime

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--days', type=int, default=1)
args = parser.parse_args()


now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
start = (now - datetime.timedelta(days=args.days)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
end = now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

cd = boto3.client('ce', 'us-west-2')

results = []

token = None
while True:
    if token:
        kwargs = {'NextPageToken': token}
    else:
        kwargs = {}
    data = cd.get_cost_and_usage(TimePeriod={'Start': start, 'End':  end}, Granularity='DAILY', Metrics=['UnblendedCost'], GroupBy=[{'Type': 'DIMENSION', 'Key': 'LINKED_ACCOUNT'}, {'Type': 'DIMENSION', 'Key': 'SERVICE'}],Filter={'Dimensions': {'Key': 'SERVICE','Values': ['AWS Lambda']}}, **kwargs)
    results += data['ResultsByTime']
    token = data.get('NextPageToken')
    if not token:
        break

print('\t'.join(['TimePeriod', 'LinkedAccount', 'Service', 'Amount', 'Unit', 'Estimated']))
for result_by_time in results:
    for group in result_by_time['Groups']:
        amount = group['Metrics']['UnblendedCost']['Amount']
        unit = group['Metrics']['UnblendedCost']['Unit']
        print(result_by_time['TimePeriod']['Start'], '\t', '\t'.join(group['Keys']), '\t', amount, '\t', unit, '\t', result_by_time['Estimated'])

client = boto3.client('ses', 'us-west-2')

responses = client.send_email(
    Source='noreply@sample.com',
    Destination={
        'ToAddresses': [
            'sample@sample.com',
        ]
    },
    Message={
        'Subject': {
            'Data': 'Lambda Billing Alarm',
            'Charset': 'UTF-8',
        },
        'Body': {
            'Html': {
                'Data': ('\t'.join(['TimePeriod', 'LinkedAccount', 'Service', 'Amount', 'Unit', 'Estimated']))
                (result_by_time['TimePeriod']['Start'], '\t', '\t'.join(group['Keys']), '\t', amount, '\t', unit, '\t', result_by_time['Estimated']),
                'Charset': 'UTF-8',               
                }
            }
        }
    )
```

I want to have an output like this on email:

[ses output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqVfQ.png)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some **misplaced parentheses** here:

```
  'Data': ('\t'.join(['TimePeriod', 'LinkedAccount', 'Service', 'Amount', 'Unit', 'Estimated']))
  (result_by_time['TimePeriod']['Start'], '\t', '\t'.join(group['Keys']), '\t', amount, '\t', unit, '\t', result_by_time['Estimated']),
            'Charset': 'UTF-8',               
            }
```

Notice the issue in the following fragment: `'Estimated']))(result_by_time`.

Basically what your code tries to do is the following `(<some_string>)(arguments)`, where `<some_string>` is `\t'.join(['TimePeriod', 'LinkedAccount', 'Service', 'Amount', 'Unit', 'Estimated'])`. Subsequently you are trying to **call a string**, explaining your error:

> “TypeError: 'str' object is not callable”

Maybe your `Data` should be:

```
  'Data': '\t'.join([result_by_time['TimePeriod']['Start'], '\t', '\t'.join(group['Keys']), '\t', amount, '\t', unit, '\t', result_by_time['Estimated'])
```

Comment: Thanks Marcin!, but still I got an error with this:
'Data': '\t'.join([result_by_time['TimePeriod']['Start'], '\t', '\t'.join(group['Keys']), '\t', amount, '\t', unit, '\t', result_by_time['Estimated'])

Comment: @Ma.KristineFrias What issue. I can only guess that `amount` and `unit` are not strings? Everthing in this join must be `str`.

Comment: I got this error:
'Data': '\t'.join([result_by_time['TimePeriod']['Start'], '\t', '\t'.join(group['Keys']), '\t', amount, '\t', unit, '\t', result_by_time['Estimated']]),               
TypeError: sequence item 8: expected str instance, bool found

Comment: @Ma.KristineFrias As I wrote, everything has to be string. I don't know the data types of your variables, you haven't included such information in the question.

Comment: @Ma.KristineFrias. You can try putting everthing into `str`, e.g., str(amount), str(unit), and other variables which are not strings.

Comment: Thanks but same error. I removed the [ ]
`'Data': '\t'.join(result_by_time['TimePeriod']['Start'], '\t', '\t'.join(group['Keys']), '\t', str(amount), '\t', str(unit), '\t', result_by_time['Estimated']),               
TypeError: join() takes exactly one argument (9 given)`.......

Then I try to remove the '\t'.join before the result_by_time:
`Invalid type for parameter Message.Body.Text.Data, value: ('2020-05-12', '\t', '541037800388\tAWS Lambda', '\t', '0.0509413595', '\t', 'USD', '\t', True), type: <class 'tuple'>, valid types: <class 'str'>`

Comment: @Ma.KristineFrias  . All elemnts should be in array `'\t'.join([elem1, elem2, elem3 ...])`

Comment: Yes but same error :
`'Data':\t'.join([result_by_time['TimePeriod']['Start'], '\t', '\t'.join(group['Keys']), '\t', str(amount), '\t', str(unit), '\t', result_by_time['Estimated']])`
TypeError: sequence item 8: expected str instance, bool found

Comment: @Ma.KristineFrias Can you specify exactly what all these elements are, their data types and values?. Otherwise, I don't know how can I help. Its just a guessing game at this point.

Comment: Sorry newbie here in python.
`amount` and `unit` are integers while `Keys` and `Estimated` are string.

botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Invalid type for parameter Message.Body.Text.Data, value: ('2020-05-12', '\t', '541037800388\tAWS Lambda', '\t', '0.0509413595', '\t', 'USD', '\t', True), type: <class 'tuple'>, valid types: <class 'str'>

Comment: @Ma.KristineFrias Your last, eighth element is `True`, which is `boolean`. Try making it into string `str(result_by_time['Estimated'])`. If this helps, acceptance of the answer would be appreciated, as I think, it addresses the original issue posted.